# decoding json doesnot work the second time

Tags: php, json, curl

I am new to using curl and json. I get proper values for $courier, $ship_id and $rate.
but no values in $obj1. I have checked my links and the json it returns is fine.
I dont know what is the problem here. Could it be something where curl does not work more than once/twice ?
Please Help. Thanks in advance.

```
<?php                           
$a = 1;
if( $a == '1' ) {

$b = 'www.somelink.com?ship_id='.$ship_id.'&service_type='.$currier_name.'&rates='.$rate;

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $b);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$obj = json_decode($result, true);
print_r($obj);

$courier = $obj['ship']['0']['Service'];
$ship_id = $obj['ship_id'];
//echo $courier;
$rate = $obj['ship']['0']['Rate'];

$currier_name = str_replace(' ', '%20', $courier);

$a = 'www.xyz.com';
$ch1 = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_URL, $a);
$result1 = curl_exec($ch1);
curl_close($ch1);

$obj1 = json_decode($result1, true);

if(empty($obj1))
{
$courier = ""; $ship_id="" ; $rate="";
$courier = $obj['ship']['1']['Service'];
$ship_id = $obj['ship_id'];
//echo $courier;
$rate = $obj['ship']['1']['Rate'];

$currier_name = str_replace(' ', '%20', $courier);

$a2 = 'www.xyz.com?ship_id='.$ship_id.'&service_type='.$currier_name.'&rates='.$rate;
echo $a2;
$ch2 = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_URL, $a2);
$result2 = curl_exec($ch2);
curl_close($ch2);

$obj1 = json_decode($result2, true);
print_r($obj1); 
}   

}
```

?>

```
<td>
<input class="carrier input-text" value="<?php echo $courier; ?>" type="text" name="carrier" id="carrier" style="width:100%;"/>
</td>
<td>
<input class="required-entry input-text" value="<?php echo $obj1['tracking_id']; ?>" type="text" id="tracking_id" name="tracking_id" style="width:100%;"/>
</td>
<td>
<input class="required-entry input-text" value="<?php echo $obj1['path']; ?>" type="text" id="label_path" name="label_path" style=""/> 
</td>
```

Comment: What is the value of `$result2`?

Comment: @BizzyBob $result2 returns nothing.

Comment: `$currier_name = str_replace(' ', '%20', $courier);` that's not the proper way to urlencode ANYTHING except spaces (and even then im guessing it might be a problem with exotic charactersets or binary data)... stop doing that, your currier name is not exclusively a combination of X number of spaces. instead, do `$a2 = 'www.xyz.com?ship_id='.urlencode($ship_id).'&service_type='.urlencode($currier_name).'&rates='.urlencode($rate);` - or better yet, `$a2='www.xyz.com?'.http_build_query(array('ship_id'=>$ship_id,'service_type'=>$currier_name,'rates'=>$rate));`

Comment: maybe try adding: `curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);`